# Можно ли, используя SQLite, обращаться к таблицам из разных файлов?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, любой-язык

Используя MySQL, я могу обращаться к таблицам из разных схем. Например, работая с MySQL в Delphi через ADO, несмотря на то, что я явно задаю схему по умолчанию (в данном случае - `dna_homo_2015may`):

```
var
  ADO1:TADOConnection;

<...>
ADO1.ConnectionString:='Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=password;'+
   'Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user1;Extended Properties="Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver;'+
   'SERVER=localhost;UID=user1;PWD=password;DATABASE=dna_homo_2015may;'+
   'PORT=3306;COLUMN_SIZE_S32=1"';
```

я могу обращаться к таблицам из нескольких схем, указывая их имена полностью:

```
Query:='select A.*, B.`id`, B.`name`'+
    'from `dna_homo_2015may`.`temp_pos` A, `dna_homo_2016june`.`genes_list` B'+
    'where <...>';
```

Могу я, используя SQLite и имея две таблицы table1 в файле base1.sdb  и table2 в файле base2.sdb, выполнить аналогичный запрос, с одновременной выборкой из этих двух таблиц? Если да, то как?

Comment: Можно к `*.csv`, как минимум, через `virtual table`: https://sqlite.org/csv.html. Для `*.sdb` надо найти соответствующий модуль.

Comment: Попробуйте написать `attach` и `select` в один запрос через `;`. И напишите содержимое сообщения об ошибке (телепаты в отпуске) :)

Comment: Покажите ваши иероглифы :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov спасибо, а можно тоже самое, но в виде текста? Вместо кнопки "Print Screen", нажмите "Ctrl+C", когда активно окно с ошибкой, а потом "Ctrl+V" здесь :)

Comment: Эти иероглифы при переводе из кодовой страницы cp_1200 в cp_1250 складываются в осмысленную фразу: "_SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns_". Надеюсь это поможет. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу, в итоге, сам. Можно, и не одним способом, хотя все они отличаются инструментами реализации, а не подходом.

Я испробовал ADO, FireDAC, объектный враппер, непосредственную работу с SQLite3.DLL и даже триальные компоненты от DevArt.
Скажу сразу - через ADO использовать два разных файла в качестве поставщиков таблиц не получится. У меня, по крайней мере, так и не получилось. Все остальные инструменты более или менее работают. Вся соль заключалась в том, что несмотря на начальное обращение к файлу таблицы (привожу пример с использованием враппера)

```
s:='P:\SQLLite_DBs\hg38-genes.sdb.db';
base:=TSQLiteDatabase.Create(s);
```

с последующим аттачем второй базы

```
s:= 'attach `P:\SQLLite_DBs\hg38-repeats.sdb.db`  as db2;';
base.ExecSQL(s);
```

ещё раз инициализировать первую таблицу, уже как db1:

```
s:= 'attach `P:\SQLLite_DBs\hg38-genes.sdb.db`  as db1;';
base.ExecSQL(s);
```

Всё. Теперь можно смело обращаться к разным таблицам из разных файлов:

```
s:='select b.id from db1.`genes-g38-201505` a, db2.`repeats-g38` b where a.`chr` = b.`chr`;';
tb:=base.GetTable(s);
```

Чтобы обращаться к таблицам из разных файлов. То же самое и с остальными способами работы с SQLite.

Однако, провозившись несколько вечеров с SQLite, я понял, что придётся отказаться от её использования: несмотря на все ухищрения, она уступает в скорости MySQL и не может работать с огромными объёмами данных на уровне геномов. Особенно это касается работы через враппер - он писался не для работы в 64-битном режиме.

А жаль: хотелось бы избавиться от обязательного наличия MySQL-сервера и инструкций, как обновлять базы.

Comment: А что, есть только две крайности, SQLite и MySQL? Тот же Firebird можно использовать без установки сервера, а возможности - как у полноценной СУБД.

Comment: @KadafiVSC Нет, разумеется. Работа с MySQL "досталась" в наследство, а сейчас просто стали проверять файловые БД на пригодность, и сразу наткнулись на проблему с двумя источниками у SQLite.

Comment: @KadafiVSC А в Firebird можно использовать несколько файлов баз без сервера?

Comment: @Alexey Kozlov Если честно, сам я запросы к нескольким БД в Firebird не пробовал делать никогда, так что не могу дать ответ. Бегло посмотрел описание таких запросов, про ограничения у встроенного сервера ничего не увидел. Единственное, что только 1 пользователь сможет работать с файлами БД. [вот можно почитать про запросы из одной БД к другой в Firebird](http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=execute_statement).